# Virus Code discovered by my Antivirus on an SO question

Tags: support, specific-question

See this question: [Trying to decode a virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321907/trying-to-decode-a-virus)

This page is blocked - it loads and then the page removed by ESET Endpoint Secuirty on my Laptop. The AntiVirus software states it has found code for PHP/Agent.NEH Trojan on the page.

This *may* be code that the question originator has put on the page as from the title tag it was something along the lines of he was trying to decode the virus (well duh).

I trust Eset, it's a fully paid up and valid Antivirus tool. The question has several upvotes and answers, so Can someone get into the page and edit the code text, add some comment characters or otherwise break the code into chunks so that I -- and others -- can load the page without the anti-virus detecting a false positive. I would prefer not to disable/unload the Antivirus.

Of course if the code text strings in the question are not the cause, something on that page is causing a detection alert and disconnection / page quarantine.

Comment: You expect me to click on that?

Comment: @MartinJames It's in a code block. It can't do anything.

Comment: @Mysticial lol - you know that 'cos you clicked on it!

Comment: The question is harmless. Or as harmless as SO posts normally are. So, just configure your antivirus-program properly, or throw it out as trash.

Comment: 'Or as harmless as SO posts normally are' - lol!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Avoid the page. If you absolutely need to see it, disable your AV software just long enough to visit the page, and then re-enable it. The question contains a text literal that probably matches the virus signature, but there's no malicious content there.

Comment: I would tell you what's in the question, but you would probably lose access to this page as well.

Comment: @MartinJames well, the question has answers and comments, so I'm hoping it's a false positive but the fact my Antivirus came back with `PHP/Agent.NEH` I'm not entirely sure, but I can't see it to judge for myself and my much better informed but much more trigger happy Antivirus thinks not.

Comment: I do not believe in editing questions just because some weird Antivirus software reports a false positive.

Comment: I just knew it would be PHP.

Comment: PHP code in an HTML page displayed in a browser cannot be malicious. Antivirus manufactures should know this.

Comment: @itchee I would not say it's a wierd antivirus, it's one of the best business AVs out there.

Comment: @itchee: They certainly can if someone is sharing infected source code to get people to spread the virus.

Comment: If you expect "business AVs" to not let you view *anything* that could be used *somewhere* as malware, then that's fine. I would instantly uninstall this piece of software, though.

Comment: @Lightness: that is just awful.

Comment: I posted that initial question - it's a code block, as another commenter says, and an attempt to figure out how my system was infected. It isn't malicious at all.

Comment: @itchee: Yes, it is awful. It's a cruel world out there.

Comment: I also had this issue and came here to ask about it. I don't know why it got so many downvotes.

Comment: @Martin: Just because it is paid up business AV software doesn't mean they cannot make mistakes though.

Comment: Heh yeah, I enjoyed the notion that the OP trusts the software simply because it is "fully paid up". Let me just go and throw some software together and charge you money for it. What would you like it to do? I promise it won't be malicious.

Answer (score -6):

I for one am glad AV picks this up. That's good. But you could put stackoverflow.com into your whitelist. Clearly nothing on this site will hurt you.

Editing the Q&A is a no-no, though. What would be its meaning, then?

Comment: Anti-Vlad? .......................

Comment: I think I'm more surprised than concerned. But cheers

Comment: I disagree. Adding websites to whitelists is nothing one should do. Stack Overflow uses ads, for example. Ad providers are a common target for malicious software and hackers and this is nothing that Stack Overflow can directly control.

Comment: @itchee: Well, any software that can't distinguish between a third-party ad network and a first-party site, these days, is likely to do more harm than good. Ad networks are so ridiculously common an exploit vector I have trouble imagining the AV companies aren't aware of that.